# Ordering div based on JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

My page contains three columns containing divs:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="portlet" id="1">1</div>
        <div class="portlet" id="2">2</div>
        <div class="portlet" id="3">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="portlet" id="4">4</div>
        <div class="portlet" id="5">5</div>
        <div class="portlet" id="6">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="portlet" id="7">7</div>
        <div class="portlet" id="8">8</div>
        <div class="portlet" id="9">9</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each portlet is sortable and draggable. I want users to be able to drag the portlets in whatever order they desire then save it. The next time they open the page the site will receive JSON data, for example:

```
var portletOrder = {"column1":["3", "4", "7"],
            "column2":["1", "9"],
            "column3":["2", "6", "8", "5"]};
```

I would like the page to sort the portlet in order based on portletOrder values.

I've created jsfiddle and I'm not quite sure how to fill inside the sort function.

https://jsfiddle.net/9v5eL8uL/

I want the expected result to look like this

```
3 1 2
4 9 6
7   8
    5
```

Comment: What is the hard part? Getting the order from the "table"? Getting the JSON from a server? Storing the JSON to a server? Something else? Please show something you've tried, we're not going to write the whole app for you.

Comment: Look at how to sort DOM elements and how to sort an array based on another array.

Comment: @Teemu, I've updated my post. Hope this clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

Not going to write the app for you, but one possible approach would be to wrap everything inside a form like

```
<form action="..." method="post"></form>
```

and add for each portlet one hidden input field inside it like

```
<div class="portlet" id="portlet-id-1">
  <input type="text" value="portlet-id-1" name="sameNameForEveryInput" style="display:none;" />portlet-id-1
</div>
<div class="portlet" id="portlet-id-2">
  <input type="text" value="portlet-id-2" name="sameNameForEveryInput" style="display:none;" />portlet-id-2
</div>
...
<input type="submit" name="submitButtonName" />
```

and submit the form using a submit button when you want to save it. Using PHP you could just do something like

```
if(isset($_POST['submitButtonName']))
{
    //do something with $_POST['sameNameForEveryInput'] which is now a array
}
```

When the page is loaded you can order the `portlets` using i.e. PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Either have your JavaScript rearrange the items in the DOM according to how they're supposed to be ordered (according to the JSON ordering info).

Alternatively, it seems like this information might be generated by some sort of server-side technology. Is the information in the JSON ordering info also coming out of the same place? Can you read that information on the server side and send the portlet HTML in the desired order?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that JSON format, you could do as follows:

1. Get the columns under "#container .column" (jQuery gets them in DOM order, so the first one in the array would correspond with column1 in your json)
2. Iterate over this list, retrieve columns from JSON object and rearrange everything.

This algorithm works because it assumes that all portlets are defined in the JSON object (otherwise, some wouldn't be moved and the result would be odd).

```
$(function () {
    var portletOrder = {"column1": ["3", "4", "7"],
        "column2": ["1", "9"],
        "column3": ["2", "6", "8", "5"]},
        // Retrieves columns in DOM order, so column1 will be element 0 of the array.
        myColumns = $("#container .column"),
        i = 1;

    myColumns.each(function() {
        var column = this;
        $.each(portletOrder['column' + i], function(_, portlet) {
            $('#' + portlet).detach().appendTo(column);
        });
        i += 1;
    });
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9v5eL8uL/1/). Hope it helps.